# Appropriate socket permissions in PNaCl

Tags: sockets, google-chrome, plugins, permissions, google-nativeclient

I am developing a PNaCl plugin for Chrome, where I need send http request to the local application.Then I found the Pepper plugin and it looks promising to achieve my goal.
But when I do it, I found that the PNaCl can't use the socket without permissions. Where is the appropriate socket permissions specified in the manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

What permissions do you currently have set? The manifest has to contain the `"sockets"` permission when you use the [`sockets.tcp`, `sockets.udp` or `sockets.tcpServer` APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp). Looking at the [sockets manifest example](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/sockets), it should look like:

```
{
  "name": "My Sockets app",
  "sockets": {
    "udp": {
      // Permission for chrome.sockets.udp.send:
      // The application is allowed to send udp packets
      // to any host:port combination.
      "send": "*"
    },
    "tcp": {
      // Permission for chrome.sockets.tcp.connect:
      // The application is allowed to connect only to the
      // tcp server on 127.0.0.1 port 80.
      "connect": "127.0.0.1:80"
    },
    "tcpServer": {
      // Permission for chrome.sockets.tcpServer.listen:
      // The application is allowed to accept new client
      // connections on the local address at port 80.
      "listen": "127.0.0.1:80"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Or are you using the confusingly-named-but-older [`"socket"` API] (note the singular versus plural above)?

Comment: Thanks for JF Bastien's answer.But I'm deviceloping a PNaCl plugin whose manifest file is differen from the chrome web app.

Comment: I want to send http request in my PNaCl plugin,but there's not socket permissions.I have developed it in NPAPI plugin,but NPAPI is disabled in the newest Chrome Browser by default.I can't access to Chrome Web Store normally,so I must use the PNaCl plugin or PPAPI plugin.I can't find the correct method to install PPAPI plugin to chrome.And there isn't enough document to explain the PPAPI plugin in Google Developer Website.Can you give some suggests?